# Is there anything i need to do with the SSD to optimize?

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd

Here at work we have a old image (2010) of Windows 7 that we install on all our clients. This is far fetch, but the new computers that are comming in have SSD and we are experiencing some instability with certain (old, very old) software.

I'm not sure if updates are updated in to the image, but the computer is set to update forever after install... so there might be a chance it's not updated right out of install but it gets updated later.

When SSD first came out there where this list of things you should do to optimize the use of the SSD, and I might think we are not doing this.

Comment: When migrating an image from a HDD to an SSD, one of the most important things to check is [if partitions are aligned](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113967-ssd-alignment.html). But can you add some more information about the specific "instability" you're facing? If apps are writing through kernel I don't see what difference would it make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 when installed on an SSD turns off indexing and so on. Instead of painstakingly trying to figure out all the changes to be made, I recommend using something like [SSD Tweaker](http://www.elpamsoft.com/?p=SSD-Tweaker):

[image]

> Optimize Windows XP, Vista and 7 for SSD Drives. With all the advice online for SSD hard drives it can take hours of research and fiddling to properly setup your SSD drive. Now with this little app you can Tweak Windows 2K/XP/Vista & 7 including x64 in seconds.
>
> **SSD Tweaker** lets you tweak the following:
>
> - Windows Services (Pro Only)
> - Query and Set Windows 7 TRIM Status (Pro Only)
> - Experimental TRIM Optimization (Pro Only)
> - Hibernation Settings (Pro Only)
> - Use Large System Cache
> - Ntfs Memory Usage
> - Disable 8.3 Filenames
> - Disable Date Stamping
> - Disable Boot Tracing
> - Windows Prefetcher
> - Windows Vista Superfetch
> - Windows Indexing Service
> - System Restore
> - Windows Defrag
> - DIPM Enable Support

Comment: While this app really allows you to "tweak" these settings, I would suggest you thoroughly investigate implications of each or its settings. When you install Win 7 on an SSD, it will automatically enable TRIM and disable Defragmentation, and with modern SSD that's about all you need. **Disabling Superfetch, for example, is complete nonsense**.

Comment: The main problem here seems to be that they're deploying existing HDD images onto SSDs. Best option IMO would be to simply create new SSD-specific optimised images for deployment, since SSDs are only going to increase in number.